# When should you use 'git pull origin' and when should you use 'git pull origin master'?

Tags: git

I normally switch to a branch and do

```
git pull origin branchname
```

or if I am on master then I do

```
git pull origin master
```

However, I saw a few places suggesting to always do

```
git pull origin
```

Are there specific use cases for using one or the other ?

Comment: hmm, maybe if you use git pull origin on your current branch, it will pull the current branch so you don't mistakenly pull the master to the current one.

Comment: @Vdt That is a good point !

Answer (score 2):

git pull is actually a shortcut command for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. In other words, git pull behind the scenes runs git fetch with the given parameters

```
$ git fetch origin #or git pull origin
```

The above command copies all branches from the remote refs/heads/ namespace and stores them to the local refs/remotes/origin/ namespace.

```
$ git fetch origin master #or git pull origin master
```

the above command ONLY copies `master` branch from the remote & stores them locally.